# Book example uses "explicit" keyword in class declaration. Is it invalid?

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I'm following a book that teaches C++ according to the standard C++11. The book shows an example that marks a subclass as `explicit`.

From what I've gathered, this will make the compiler check for errors that have to do with dynamic binding, and you must also explicitly use the `override` keyword whenever you override a virtual function otherwise it won't work. I did set up a small program to test this but I got an error. And I've never seen examples of the keyword `explicit` be used like that anywhere else anyway.

Has the book provided inaccurate information or have I just missed something? Should I just use the `override` keyword on it's own instead?

```
class base {
public:
    virtual void f() {
        cout << "Called from base" << endl;
    }
};

class derived explicit : public base {
public:
    void f() override {
        cout << "Called from derived" << endl;
    }
};
```

---

Writing `c++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe` in the terminal gave me the following error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id 
class derived explicit : public base {
                   ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `explicit` this way is not valid C++, in any standard. From cppreference on [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

> 1) Specifies that a constructor or conversion function (since C++11) is explicit, that is, it cannot be used for implicit conversions and copy-initialization.
>   2) [...] (C++20 specific...)

... and most importantly:

> The explicit specifier may only appear within the decl-specifier-seq of the declaration of a constructor or conversion function (since C++11) within its class definition.

This does not cover the case you have shown from the book. Have a look at the [curated list of books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and consider switching to one of those.